# Concavity near the boundary of the distance function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, convex-analysis

I was reading the paper

> Quelques remarques sur les problemes elliptiques quasilineaires du
> second ordre, P. L. Lions, Journal d’Analyse Mathématique volume 45,
> pages 234–254(1985)

and on page 251 he claims that (using it in the proof), the distance function near the boundary is concave for a general open bounded domain, which I don't think it is true. I can get this fact if the domain is convex, is there any result saying this for a non-convex domain? Say, interior ball condition is enough?

---

Edit: On page 251, here is the part I suspected that he used that fact:
\begin{align}
|u(\overline{x}-s\mathbf{n}(\overline{x}))-u(y)| &= |u(\overline{x}-s\mathbf{n}(\overline{x}))-u(\overline{y} - s\mathbf{n}(\overline{y}))|\\
&\leq \frac{C}{s^{1-\theta}}|\overline{x} - s\mathbf{n}(\overline{x}) - y|.
\end{align}
My reasoning is that, he has $|\nabla u(x)\leq \frac{C}{d(x)^{1-\theta}}$ earlier. Therefore to connect the line between $\overline{x}-s\mathbf{n}(\overline{x})$ and $y = \overline{y}-s\mathbf{n}(\overline{y})$ we need that every point on this line segment need to have distance bigger or equal to the distance from $\overline{x}-s\mathbf{n}(\overline{x})$ or $y$, in short, we want
\begin{equation}
d_{\partial \Omega}\Big(\lambda\big(\overline{x}-s\mathbf{n}(\overline{x})\big)+(1-\lambda )y\Big) \geq s
\end{equation}
provided that at $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda  = 1$ we have
\begin{equation}
d_{\partial\Omega}(y) = d_{\partial\Omega}(\overline{x}-s\mathbf{n}(\overline{x})) = s.
\end{equation}
We could say quasi-concave is enough, but I do believe he meant concave.

Comment: You're sure about the reference ? I checked page 251 and I don't see where this is stated or used.

Comment: See edit. I just added some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain is assumed regular therefore at least Lipschitz in my opinion, and this is sufficient to ensure quasi-convexity of the domain. This means that for $z_1,z_2\in \Omega$ you have $\mathrm{d}_\Omega(z_1,z_2) \lesssim_\Omega |z_1-z_2|$ where $\mathrm{d}_\Omega$ is the geodesic distance (minimal length of a continuous $\Omega$-valued path between the two points).
Here you have the assumption $s\geq |x-y|$ so WLOG $s>0$. In particular $\overline{x}-s \mathbf{\overline{x}}$ and $y$ are two points of $\Omega$ and you can therefore use your estimate on the gradient on the given path.

For a reference about quasi-convexity you can check Sections 2.5.1 and 2.5.2 of

> Brudnyi, A.; Brudnyi, Y., Methods of geometric analysis in extension and trace problems.
> Volume 1. Monographs in Mathematics, 102. Birkh¨auser/Springer, 2012.

EDIT : sorry, I got confused in the previous answer. You invoke the quasi-convexity of $\partial\Omega$ to get the existence of a map $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\partial\Omega$ linking $\overline{x}$ to $\overline{y}$. Then, $\gamma_s(\sigma):=\gamma(\sigma)-s\mathbf{n}(\gamma(\sigma))$ maps $\overline{x}-s\mathbf{n}(\overline{x})$ to $y$ and satisfies $\mathrm{d}_{\partial_\Omega}(\gamma_s)\geq s$ all the way. The length of $\gamma_s$ should be (I confess, I did not check it) comparable to the one of $\gamma$, which is, by quasi-convexity, comparable to $|\overline{x}-\overline{y}|$, itself comparable to $|x-y|$ (beginning of page 251).

That's just the idea that in $\Omega= \mathbf{R}^2\setminus \text{B}(0,1)$ to connect two points $x$ and $y$ of norm $1+\varepsilon$, you do not follow the straightline but a portion of arc (of radius $1+\varepsilon$).

Comment: But I need a lower bound on the distance, i.e., quasi-convexity is not enough here, I want quasi-concavity of the distance, right?

Comment: You're right, I got confused, I corrected the answer, hope it works out for you !

Comment: Thank you! I am checking it out now.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!